# cache alignment of a struct with declspec(align())

Tags: c++, winapi

I know a little bit what is cache alignment and what will happen when we used it.

```
#define CACHE_LINE  32
#define CACHE_ALIGN __declspec(align(CACHE_LINE))
struct CACHE_ALIGN S1 { // cache align all instances of S1
   int a, b, c, d;
};
struct s1;
```

for example, in the above example, s1 is 32-byte cache aligned but I can't get why the following code defined like this:

```
struct __declspec(align(CACHE_ALIGN)) CUSTINFO {
    // Force each structure to be in a different cache line.
    DWORD m_customer_id;        // Mostly read-only
    wchar_t m_name[100];        // Mostly read-only

    // Force the following members to be in a different cache line.
    __declspec(align(CACHE_ALIGN))
    int m_balance;                  // Read-write
    FILETIME m_last_order_date;     // Read-write
};
```

Why two times __declspec(align(CACHE_ALIGN)) is used in the struct? Why should even align our structure? can someone explain these two code snippets in detail?

Comment: You'll probably see that there's a gap between the first two fields and the two following fields. "_Force the following members to be in a different cache line_" as it says.

Comment: How much gap is there?

Comment: Are you familiar with what a cache line is? Do you know what "false sharing" is? Do you know what `__declspec(align(..))` does? If you research those, then you'll will understand.